# Confusion on using this/that and that/those

Tags: american-english, pronouns, that, this-that

I have confusion regarding the use of that/those and this/that properly.

My first question:

1. Jobs those are generally involved in a lot of repetitive work are boring.
2. Jobs that are generally involved in a lot of repetitive work are boring.

I think the first one is correct because we refer more than one job so we should use the connecting word `those`. However, Grammarly shows that the second one is right.

Can anyone explain the reason?

My second question:

1. We’re going to eat first and then go to the film. Are you happy with that?
2. We’re going to eat first and then go to the film. Are you happy with this?

As per Grammarly, we should use that instead of this. Can anyone explain the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to your first question:

(2) is correct -- the sentence is uging *that* as a preposition, not a pronoun, so it cannot take a plural. You would say *those jobs are boring* (pronoun use), but when you are using *that* to produce a restrictive clause, it will always be *that*.

With respect to your second question:

Both options are grammatical and both options are idiomatic English.

Comment: To elaborate on the second question - we use _this_ when speaking of something nearby, and _that_ for something further away. Your sentences refer to an _idea_ (a plan for how to spend the evening), not a physical object, so _this_ and _that_ are both acceptable.